# Unable to cout char

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cout, cin

I can't understand the problem here so i hope some can help out
I have program start out like this int main():

```
    Board br;
    GetNames();
    br.PresentPlayer();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

GetNames() looks like this:

```
char p[100];
char p2[100];
Board br;
cout << "Please Enter Player 1's Name:";
cin >> _player_name_1;
cout << "Please Enter " << _player_name_1 << "'s Symbol(Make sure its 1 characters long):";
cin >> p;
cout << "Please Enter Player 2's Name:";
cin >> _player_name_2;
cout << "Please Enter " << _player_name_2 << "'s Symbol(Make sure its 1 characters long):";
cin >> p2;
br.SetSymbols(p[0], p2[0]);
```

Board::SetSymbols(char p,char p2) looks like this:

```
void Board::SetSymbols(char p1,char p2)
{
_player_char_1 = p1;
_player_char_2 = p2;
_current_player = _player_char_1;
cout << _current_player << endl;
}
```

Variables are in Board.h:

```
char _player_char_1;
char _player_char_2;
char _current_player;
```

And lastly PresentPlayer():

```
void Board::PresentPlayer()
{
cout << _current_player << endl;

}
```

So when SetSymbols is executed it prints out _player_char_1 correctly
however when PresentPlayer is executed It prints out those symbols that you would do this alt+numlock numbers

why is this happening??

Comment: Why do you have `Board::SetSymbols` twice?

Comment: What is `PresentPlayer`?

Comment: You have two copies of Board br. You set the data in one and then you print the values in another.

Comment: `br` in `main()` is not the same as `br` in `GetNames`.

Comment: I have Added PresentPlayer to my question

Answer (score -5):

```
char _player_char_1;
char _player_char_2;
char _current_player;
```

should be

```
char *_player_char_1;
char *_player_char_2;
char *_current_player;
```

Or, since you're using C++, *stop* using `char*` (you're not allocating memory for them, or checking bounds), use `std::string` instead.

```
void Board::SetSymbols(char p1,char p2)
```

needs to be

```
void Board::SetSymbols(char *p1,char *p2)
```

or even better

```
void Board::SetSymbols(std::string &p1, std::string &p2)
```

Comment: If not `std::string`, then at least use `char[]` instead of `char*` for the players, and make sure to use `std::setw` to avoid buffer overflows from `cin >>`.

Comment: What do you mean "you are not allocating memory for them?"

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: A pointer needs to point to something. The more I look at this code, the more my head hurts. I thought you were pointing it to the allocated arrays, but apparently not.

Comment: Why should something called `_player_char_1` be a `std::string` and not a `char`?